# Pure CSS custom radio button (whole width)

Tags: html, css

I wish to style a radio button like this using CSS only (no background image):

[image: Radio button whole width]

Left: checked / right: unchecked

I know how to replace the radio dot or the tick from the checkbox - there are plenty of tutorials on the internet regarding that - but I couldn't find a way to make the rectangle sit behind the label text like this (rectangle to be 100% of the input's size & leave no extra blank space around it).

Compatibility with older browsers (IE8) should be taken into account.

This is my html (I'm using bootstrap):

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
  <input type="radio" id="gender_woman" name="gender" value="madame" checked>
  <label for="connexion_madame">MADAME</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
  <input type="radio" id="gender_man" name="gender" value="monsieur">
  <label for="connexion_monsieur">MONSIEUR</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree with the above comment. You haven't even tried, it's like you're trying to get your job done by someone else without paying.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Paulie_D but I've tried it several ways, and the best result I could get was either an unresponsive label text: 
 - on horizontal resize of the window my text was not modifying its padding along with the width of the rectangle - I used percentage for padding in that case;
or the other method: 
 - my rectangle was in front of the label's text so that only the white background of the rectangle was visible

Comment: I realized what I've been doing wrong thanks to Quiet Tran's answer. We can chill now. Thank you all!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I don't use bootstrap)

**HTML**

```
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="MADAME">
  <span>MADAME</span>
</label>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="MONSIEUR">
  <span>MONSIEUR</span>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
label.radio {
  cursor: pointer;
}
label.radio input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}
label.radio span {
  padding: 7px 14px;
  border: 2px solid #EEE;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #009BA2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
label.radio input:checked + span {
  border-color: #009BA2;
}
```

Link JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/edbmwz0c/

Hope can help you

Answer (score -2):

I think you can style it the same way as the buttons,so  I think this should do the trick

```
 .checkbox{
    //other stuff
    background-color: #ffffff !important;

}
```

It's important to use !important beacuse that way you override the bootstraps styling