# Better visibility of radio button in a table -- CSS only solution

Tags: css, html-table, radio-button

Radio buttons are much too small to be easily seen on a tablet or phone display. I have an application with radio buttons in a table where I can only change CSS easily, no HTML, no Javascript.

[image: Background of selected radio button]

I am looking for a CSS-only solution to get something like shown above. It may look differently, and the radio button can be totally removed, it just should stand out well enough.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td >
        <input ref="input" id="s1" value="we" name="a" type="radio" checked>
      </td>     
      <td >
        <input ref="input" id="s2" value="343" name="a" type="radio">
      </td>     
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[A fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmenne/tzoskmeL/40/)

Comment: I don't think its possible with only css maximum you can do is use the :active psudo selector but that also wont retain the background. The only way to do this is to check for a click event in javascript and then change the background by Dom manipulation

Comment: `and the radio button can be totally removed, it just should stand out well enough.` . So the button can be removed but the same button should stand out. How would it stand out if it's not there ? Or maybe i don't understand your question. The thing i can tell you is that you cannot style radio/select/checkboxes and have 100% cross browser compatibility

Comment: Something like https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons

Comment: To achieve something like that definitely requires changes in HTML, javascript/jquery. Bootstrap is a complete framework on its own. Changing the styling of checkboxes and radio buttons by pure css is not possible as we need to handle click event and its active status. However if you ok to change the appearance of the radio button itself by using pseudo selectors here is a stackoverflow link with similar solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222830/pure-css-custom-radio-button-whole-width

Comment: Thanks, I had see that, but it requires a <label> wrapper.